# How to use npm.commands.version to bump the package.json version programatically

Tags: node.js, npm, version

I'd like the package.json version of my project to bump up every time I run my project, for that I installed the npm package into my project as a local node-module but the following does not work:

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(function (e, n) {
    n.commands.version("patch", function (error) { 
        // 'error' here equals an error message as shown below
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**Error message**
"npm version [ | major | minor | patch | prerelease | preminor | premajor ](run in package dir)'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (2.4.1)'npm view  version' to view a package's published version'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions"

Any idea what's missing and how to make it work?

Thanks!

Btw, I don't use grunt and not planning to at this point, so grunt-bump is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when I read the docs, I see "Like all other commands, this function takes a string array as its first parameter", which means you need `["patch"]` where you have `"patch"`:

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(function (e, n) {
    n.commands.version(["patch"], function (error) {
        // 'error' here equals an error message as shown below
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

That works fine for me.

Comment: Guess I missed the fact that it needs to be an array :) Thanks for the help. Works for me too now.

Comment: How do you set the package directory when doing this?